# django installation not working virtualenv

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have installed virtualenv

```
pip3 install virtualenv
```

create a virtualenv

```
virtualenv djangoenv
```

access the virtualenv

```
source ./djangoenv/bin/activate
```

Then I install

```
pip3 install django
```

when `import django` I get error`no module named django`

`django-admin.py --version` displalys `1.9.4` So it is installed. what am I doing wrong ??

Comment: How are you doing `import django`? Executing a file or shell? Check the path of the python executable you are using.

Comment: using the python3 interpreter, it came by default installed with ubuntu

Comment: Check `which python3` that path should go to your `djangoenv` folder instead of `/usr/bin/python3`. What is the output for `which python3`?

Comment: `/home/edjroz/djangoenv/bin/python3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install virtualenv with pip :

```
sudo pip install virtualenv
```

create Virtualenv

```
virtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python3 virtualenv_name
```

activte Virtualenv

```
source virtualenv_name/bin/activate
```

finally install django

```
pip install django
```

With that you will get django installed using python3